# Improving query performance to search in clob column in big table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a big table (about 4.6 million records) with many columns, I have concatenated some columns and inserted it in clob column(one column have an alias of the name so the name came in a different way and it inserted in clob column )and that column with ctxsys.context index.

I searched with contains a function with the fuzzy operator and for performance, I added tow columns to search and those columns with a bitmap index
and analyzed the table by using **DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS()** also I alter my index to take parallel with 4 degrees and increase SORT_AREA_SIZE to 8300000.

My problem is when I searched it's taken from 2 to 5 min to executed.
is there any way to improve performance and reduce time execution(another algorithm to speed searching or I can change the structure of my table by increase the columns and search in multiple columns).

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT first_name, 
       last_name, 
       countries, 
       category, 
       aliases 
FROM  (SELECT first_name, 
              last_name, 
              countries, 
              category, 
              aliases, 
              rr 
       FROM  (SELECT T.u_id, 
                     T.first_name, 
                     T.last_name, 
                     T.countries, 
                     T.category, 
                     T.aliases, 
                     ROWNUM rr, 
                     all_data 
              FROM   tbl_rsk_list_world T 
              WHERE  t.countries = 'SPAIN' 
                     AND category = 'Eng') 
       WHERE  Contains(all_data, 'fuzzy(JOSE,60,,weight)', 1) > 0) 
WHERE  rr BETWEEN 1 AND 500
```

The Execution plan is:

```
SQL> select * from TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2747287528
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                    | 20651 |   109M|  5724   (1
|*  1 |  VIEW                  |                    | 20651 |   109M|  5724   (1
|   2 |   COUNT                |                    |       |       |
|   3 |    PX COORDINATOR      |                    |       |       |
|   4 |     PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000           | 20651 |  4638K|  5724   (1
|   5 |      PX BLOCK ITERATOR |                    | 20651 |  4638K|  5724   (1
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| TBL_RSK_LIST_WORLD | 20651 |  4638K|  5724   (1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("CTXSYS"."CONTAINS"("ALL_DATA",'fuzzy(jose,60,,weight)',1)>0 AND "
              AND "from$_subquery$_002"."RR">=1)
   6 - filter("COUNTRIES"='SPAIN' AND "CATEGORY"='Eng')

20 rows selected
```

when I using FIRST_ROWS and DOMAIN_INDEX_NO_SORT hints the execution plan be:

```
SQL> select * from TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1488722846
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                        |    50 |   173K|
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |                        |    50 |   173K|
|   2 |   COUNT                       |                        |       |       |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TBL_RSK_LIST_WORLD     |    50 | 11500 |
|*  4 |     DOMAIN INDEX              | NDX_RSK_LIST_WORLD_CTX |       |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   1 - filter("CATEGORY"='Eng' AND "COUNTRIES"='SPAIN' AND
              "from$_subquery$_002"."RR"<=500 AND "from$_subquery$_002"."RR">=1)
   4 - access("CTXSYS"."CONTAINS"("W"."ALL_DATA",'fuzzy(jose,60,,weight)',1)>0)

18 rows selected
```

but still the performance bad :\

Comment: please run an explain plan and post the results

Comment: Start with the innermost query and measure/tune that. I would expect `countries` and `category` to be indexed. Also could you try having the the `CONTAINS` and the countries/category conditions in the same level?

Comment: can you add the query with the hints ? by your query I guess you are using Oracle Text to look inside the clob. Can you also put the execution time and how you define bad performance . What do you expect as elapsed time ?

Comment: Its FTS on this `6 - filter("COUNTRIES"='SPAIN' AND "CATEGORY"='Eng')` . Please add an index on these two columns, analyse the index, clear the cache, then retry.